# Обособление определения «жгуч и ярок»

Tags: пунктуация, определения

(1) **Не нужна запятая?**

```
  Из страны, где солнца свет
  Льется с неба(,) жгуч и ярок,
  Я привез себе в подарок
  Пару звонких кастаньет.
             Максимилиан Волошин
```

(2) **А здесь?**

```
  Льется с неба(,) жгуч и ярок(,)  
  Солнца свет.
```

Как объяснить выбор знаков?

**["Кастаньеты"](https://yandex.ru/video/preview/7774826359698009207)**

Comment: Я бы в первом случае обособила, т.к. эти слова воспринимаются скорее как определения. Однородные определения, стоящие после определяемого слова, должны обособляться. Но даже если они сказуемые, надо разделить - однородные сказуемые должны разделяться запятой.
А во втором случае не стала бы ставить вторую запятую, т.к. эти слова уже выступают в роли сказуемых. Если же их воспринимать как определения, усеченные прилагательные, то можно и без запятых, но стиль текста меняется, веет стариной.

Comment: Спасибо за ваше мнение (жаль, что в комментарии, а не в ответе). Интересный вариант, правда, у меня совсем другие предположения)  Но давайте послушаем, что думают наши участники.  Красивые стихи, а запись текста может вызывать вопросы.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Думаю, определения "жгуч и ярок" должны быть обособлены, и об этом пишет Д.Розенталь. Помню его правило, что если определение оторвано от определяемого слова другими членами предложения, то такое определение обособляется в любом случае. Он приводит пример: "Стрелы упали, жалкие, обратно на землю". Здесь как раз такой случай.

Comment: Спасибо за ваш ответ, голос от меня. Вроде бы все верно, определения должны быть обособлены.  Это пункт 9 Розенталя http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=108#pp108 9. Распространенное или одиночное определение обособляется, если оно отделено от существительного другими членами предложения (независимо от того, находится ли определение впереди или после определяемого слова).  Но вот автор не обособляет определения, а почему?  Для этого должны быть причины: или есть корректирующее правило, или это чем-либо обусловленная авторская пунктуация.

Comment: Спасибо, Sharon, за поддержку моей позиции. Получить одобрение от такого корифея - это дорогого стОит

Comment: Спасибо, Виктор, за высокую оценку,  но корифеем я себя точно не считаю)) Чуть позже я дам свой ответ, где попробую догадаться, почему автор не обособил свои определения. И тогда мы обсудим вариант.

Comment: Спасибо еще раз. Я  благодарю вас за внимание к теме и принимаю ваш ответ, который помог мне решить задачу.

Comment: Виктор, рад вас видеть. Давно вас не слышно и невидно.

Comment: Дорогой  Серж, спасибо за приветствие. Отрадно чувствовать, что кто-то тебя помнит. Мне приятно, что Вы меня вспомнили, но хочу Вас успокоить: я каждый день здесь уже многие годы, однако реже стал писать из-за большой загрузки работой. Выбираю вопросы, которые  мне по зубам.  Посмотрел Ваш профиль. Вы, оказывается, из Армении! С восторгом вспоминаю свою командировку на форум, который проходил в Ереване в 1985 году. Незабываемые воспоминания!

Answer (score 2):

1. *Льется с неба, **жгуч и ярок,** солнца свет.*

Обособление определений **не вызывает** сомнения. В данном случае это **краткие** прилагательные, которые могут обособляться по тем же правилам, что и **полные**: *И сверкает асфальта река, **Широка, глубока**.*

**[Розенталь, пункт 9](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=109#pp109)**  9. Распространенное или одиночное определение обособляется, если оно **отделено** от существительного другими членами предложения (независимо от того, находится ли определение впереди или после определяемого слова).

2. **Стихотворение:**

   ```
   Из страны, где солнца свет
   Льется с неба жгуч и ярок,
   Я привез себе в подарок
   Пару звонких кастаньет.
   ```

Отсутствие обособления также можно обосновать **правилами**, если считать, что определения входят в состав **сказуемого**.

**Розенталь:**  2. Не обособляются распространенные определения: 3) связанные по смыслу не только с подлежащим, но и **со сказуемым**, в состав которого они входят: *Вечером Екатерина Дмитриевна **прибежала** из Юридического клуба **взволнованная и радостная** (А. Т.); Море у его ног **лежало безмолвное и белое** от облачного неба (Пауст.).*

3. Таким образом, **возможность выбора** есть, но нужно определить причину такого выбора. В стихотворении Волошина определительный оборот входит **в состав придаточного**, поэтому его обособление **нежелательно**.

Comment: Согласен, я бы тоже не стал обособлять.

Comment: Спасибо за голос.

Comment: Sharon, меня всегда восхищает Ваше языковое чутье, но мне кажется, в данном случае оно Вас немного подводит. Дитмар Эльяшевич приводит убедительные примеры тесной связи определений не только с подлежащим, но и со сказуемым, и эти примеры безупречны. Море не просто "лежало",но "лежало безмолвное и белое" . Екатерина не просто"прибежала из клуба", но прибежала  взволнованная и радостная. Слова "лежало", "прибежала" - это глагольные связки наподобие "было, была" в составных именных сказуемых.  В нашем же случае "свет жгуч и ярок", а не "льется жгуч и ярок", поэтому "жгуч и ярок"-это определения

Answer (score 1):

Ответ **по комментарию**

Стихотворение Волошина — как **разноцветная палитра** художника! Испанский зной, какой он? Как представить себе жгучий полдень жарким летом, особенно в мутном и туманном **Париже**?

Конечно же автору важно подчеркнуть, что солнечный свет жгучий и яркий: ***Из страны**, где солнца свет // **Льется** с неба **жгуч и Ярок...***  Ударение переходит **на определение** и логически его **подчеркивает.**

**И немного о грамматике.**

**Составное именное сказуемое**, выраженное прилагательным в форме И.п., — это частный случай **трехчастной** конструкции. Такое прилагательное называют **дуплексивом,** так как оно связано и с подлежащим, и со сказуемым (двойная связь). Определение согласуется с **подлежащим** в роде и числе, а **падеж** ему задает глагол.

**В общих правилах Розенталя** говорится, что прилагательное **входит** в сказуемое (упрощенное понимание). Поэтому автор по структуре предложения может выбрать любой **грамматический** вариант: обособить или не обособить определение.

**Двойную** связь особенно хорошо видно в том случае, если глагол задает прилагательному Т.п.: *Он вернулся **расстроенный*** (И.п.) или ***расстроенным*** (Т.п.).

Comment: Спасибо. Знаю, что Вы уделяете особое внимание звучащей речи с ее интонационными переливами, и это побуждает согласиться с Вами.

Comment: Спасибо вам за интересную дискуссию! Это действительно так, про переливы звучащей речи.  Но грамматику и семантику  я учитываю тоже,  на всякий случай) А то еще подумают,  что я умею решать задачи только ударением))